# Как вывести зубчатый массив?

Tags: c#, массивы

```
string[][] zmass = new string[5][];

zmass[0] = new string[4] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
zmass[1] = new string[3] { "e", "f", "g" };
zmass[2] = new string[5] { "h", "i", "j", "k", "l" };
zmass[3] = new string[6] { "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r" };
zmass[4] = new string[2] { "s", "t" };
```

Как вывести на экран консоли?

Comment: В стандартной терминологии это *ступенчатые* массивы.

Comment: ок)

п.с. чувак который выкладывал код с foreach и удалил, там работает... это я впакался, не правильно написал у себя

Comment: Написал из головы, не проверяя, посему решил, что раз не работает, то неправильно написал. Да пофик, тут же есть уже правильный ответ. Кстати, почему бы его не принять?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для массивов в шарпе есть метод Length().

```
for (i = 0; i < zmass.Length(); i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < zmass[i].Length; j++) Write(zmass[i][j]+" ");
   writeln()
}
```

только это для общего случая массивов, а здесь string...

Comment: так работает, только Length без скобок ))

Answer (score 9):

Без лямбд, индексов и прочих избыточных для данной задачи вещей.

```
public static void WriteArray2d<T>(this T[][] array) {
    foreach (var row in array) 
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", row));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

А может быть вот так:

```
foreach (var sar in zmass)
    Console.WriteLine(sar.Aggregate((a, b) => a + " " + b));
```

Comment: =)
для полноты функционального стиля:

    zmass.Select(el => el.Aggregate(String.Empty, (aсс, e) => aсс + e + " ") + "\n").ToList().ForEach(str => Console.Write(str));

Comment: @Spectre думал про это, но не хотелось ToList использовать, чтобы не копировать лишние данные. А для простого перечислителя почему-то ForEach не предусмотрен :-(

Comment: где-то слышал, что он противоречит возможностям PLINQ, но никто не мешает написать свой Extension Method.

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach(string[] strarr in zmass)
{
    foreach(string str in strarr)
        Console.Write(str+" ");
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Update: поправил, а то я изначально выводил все элементы через строку, а не пробел.